# Using Multiprocessing to make parallel predictions in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, multiprocessing

I am trying to run inference on a large regression model with GBs of data to process. I tried to parallelize the prediction loop but it is not working as expected. This is the code that I am trying to run:

```
def predict_batch(batch):
    
    batch_idx, (inputs) = batch
    
    losses = []
    true = []
    predicted = []

    with torch.no_grad():
        y_output = model(current,calibrated)


        # making predictions here

        loss = loss_fn()
        
        overall_loss = loss.item()
            
        losses.append(overall_loss)

    # taking the outputs of each batch and making it into two lists; predicted and true
    return losses, true, predicted
```

Does someone have any boilerplate code for this which I can use?

I tried the above but it takes a lot of time for any process to run.

Here is the parallelization code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tqdm
import time
model.share_memory()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   with Pool(4) as p:
      r = list(tqdm.tqdm(p.imap(predict_batch,predict_batch_input), total=len(predict_batch_input)))
```

Comment: Where have you parallelized anything there?  Where is the multiprocessing?

Comment: Sorry for that! I added the updated code I am putting in predict_batch_input  = list(enumerate(test_loader))

Comment: That code implies that you are building the model in each process.  Is that true?  Why don't you  build it once and share it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to run four child processes, each predicting on the passed batch data. The main issue I see with the attempted approach is that each child process will be using the exact same set of data on prediction, so each child process will perform the exact same work and (for all intents and purposes) have the exact same outputs, making multiprocessing moot.

Child processes should use their own subset of data. For example, if your input data is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, then you'd probably want child processes 0-3 to have input data `[0, 1]`, `[2, 3]`, `[4, 5]`, `[6, 7]`, respectively, and pass each one of those to their respective process. Otherwise, the way you have it currently, each child process will receive `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` and do the same work on it.

```python
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


# pass shared queue to function used by child processes to store data
def predict_batch(batch, queue):
    ...
    with torch.no_grad():
        ...

    queue.put((losses, true, predicted))

    return losses,true,predicted

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(4)
    q = Manager().Queue()

    # ideally predict_batch_input would be something that is split between the processes and not the same passed variable for all n processes
    batch_inputs = [batch0, batch1, batch2, batch3]

    r = [pool.apply_async(predict_batch, args=(i, q)), len(i) for i in batch_inputs]
    
    # make parent process wait for child processes to finish
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # get data from queue
    results = [(i, j, k) for i, j, k in [q.get() for _ in range(q.qsize())]]
```

With multiprocessing in Python, unless you debug or manually code for exception handling, and errors that occur in a child process will just terminate that process without an error message being displayed. So if you see something in the child process not happening, yet the parent process finishes, there's most likely an error somewhere in the child process.

I'm not sure if this is the boilerplate you're looking for, but this is pretty similar to how I use multiprocessing with Pytorch.

I don't know how the predict_batch_input is created, but if it can be iterated, assuming a numpy array, you could maybe make the four subsets like this (I know it may not be efficient, but this is more so just to give an idea):

```python
import numpy as np


batch0, batch1, batch2, batch3 = [], [], [], []
for idx, i in enumerate(predict_batch_input):
    if idx % 4 == 0:
        batch0.append(i)
    elif idx % 4 == 1:
        batch1.append(i)
    elif idx % 4 == 2:
        batch2.append(i)
    else:  # could be elif if you want to make sure it's every fourth index
        batch3.append(i)
batch0, batch1, batch2, batch3 = np.asarray(batch0), np.asarray(batch1), np.asarray(batch2), np.asarray(batch3)
```